# .net 2.0 accessing .net 4.0 dll via assembly bindings

Tags: .net-2.0, web-services, .net-4.0

I have a .net 2.0 webservices using .net 2.0 librarys (dll). My config uses assembly binding to use the latest builds,Now the .net2.0 will be migrated to .net 4.0, does this mean i have to move my service to 4.0 as well?

Thanks 
Gauls

Comment: What do you mean by "the .net2.0 will be migrated to .net 4.0" exactly? The two can happily coexist on a machine...

Comment: .net 2.0 project will be converted to 4.0 project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

running web app under clr 4.0 which can be done by changing IIS applicaton pool for the site to use .net 4.0.